# FOP to PDF - using variable in FOP tag (URL tag)

Tags: variables, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I´m working with FOP and creating PDF files from XML.
**Can I use variables in FOP?**

Here is an example what I mean and imagine:

```
<!-- Something like this
 string x = "<fo:inline type="text" description="title" sourceid="00000000007ea0003003e"/>"-->

        
        <fo:block>
            <fo:basic-link external-destination="url('"https://www.website.com/"& x &"'")">
                <fo:inline type="text" description="title" sourceid="000006000034d0001003e"/>
            </fo:basic-link>
        </fo:block>
```

I need to put the variable `x` into the URL of the Link in that PDF. Something like this was my first idea.

Background to that case:

- String `x` is dynamic and changes every run.
- It is for about 30.000 PDFs, so I need a solution where I can use a dynamic generated link.

I hope you understand my question and you can help me :)

Comment: That is typically done at the XSL stage by passing in a parameter to the transform. How are you creating the XSL FO? Are you using XML and XSLT?

Comment: Hello, Kevin thanks for your answer. I will find out your question and write it here.

Comment: I am creating the XSL FO with a python script that I dont wrote. And yes I´m using XML and XSLT.

Comment: What I have to do in the XSL stage ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide details of which transformer you are using, but most all should support the concept of parameters passed into the transformation. Parameters are a way to send external data into the transform process.

If you are using python, then perhaps what you are looking for could be doing the transform with libxslt, but who knows?

To use libxslt you could do something like this:

```
dict = {'sourceid': '00000000007ea0003003e'}
styledoc = libxml2.parseFile("myxslt.xsl")
style = libxslt.parseStylesheetDoc(styledoc)
doc = libxml2.parseFile("myxml.xml")
result = style.applyStylesheet(doc, dict)
```

So dict is passing in a name/value pair to set the sourceid for the transformation.

You could be using a different transformer and then would need to look into the documentation for it. Parameters are name/value pairs so you could modify the XSL to accept such a parameter, let's call it "sourceid". Then your XSL would have something like this at the top to accept the parameter:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:param name="sourceid"/>
  ...
```

The addition of the parameter "sourceid" above make the value of whatever "sourceid" is passed in available in transforms.

You could use that in your templates then like this:

```
 <fo:basic-link external-destination="url('"https://www.website.com/"& x &"'")">
    <fo:inline type="text" description="title" sourceid="{$sourceid}"/>
 </fo:basic-link>
```

Although, I would note that your text content for what you have shown is blank (there is nothing in the actual fo:inline). And "sourceid" is a meaningless variable to an FO processor. Perhaps you meant to put some text in like "Click here for " along with the sourceid and would do something like this:

```
 <fo:basic-link external-destination="url('"https://www.website.com/"& x &"'")">
    <fo:inline type="text" description="title">
       <xsl:text>Click here for </xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="$sourceid"/>
       <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
    </fo:inline>
 </fo:basic-link>
```

And if that sourceid was meant to be passed into the URL, you could do that too. The line you have written for the external destination makes no sense to me, but I think you were only showing a sample.

The key is, you have passed in "sourceid" into the transformation in some way, and then by using $sourceid in the transform, you get the value.